# WCF Client connection times out

Tags: c#, wcf

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: The open operation did not
>   complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I have a host setup like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- Before deployment, you should remove the returnFaults behavior configuration to avoid disclosing information in exception messages -->
      <service name="ListPublishSubscribe.Service.PubSubService" behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/PubSubService/Service.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint contract="ListPublishSubscribe.Service.IPubSubService" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" address="" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>


<% @ServiceHost Language=C# Debug="true" Service="ListPublishSubscribe.Service.PubSubService" CodeBehind="Service.cs" %>

using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ListPublishSubscribe.Service
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://ListPublishSubscribe.Service", SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IPubSubContract))]
    public interface IPubSubService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
        void Subscribe();
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
        void Unsubscribe();
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        void PublishNameChange(string Name);
    }

    public interface IPubSubContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void NameChange(string Name);
    }

    public class ServiceEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class PubSubService : IPubSubService
    {
        public delegate void NameChangeEventHandler(object sender, ServiceEventArgs e);
        public static event NameChangeEventHandler NameChangeEvent;

        IPubSubContract ServiceCallback = null;
        NameChangeEventHandler NameHandler = null;

        public void Subscribe()
        {
            ServiceCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPubSubContract>();
            NameHandler = new NameChangeEventHandler(PublishNameChangeHandler);
            NameChangeEvent += NameHandler;
        }

        public void Unsubscribe()
        {
            NameChangeEvent -= NameHandler;
        }

        public void PublishNameChange(string Name)
        {
            ServiceEventArgs se = new ServiceEventArgs();
            se.Name = Name;
            NameChangeEvent(this, se);
        }

        public void PublishNameChangeHandler(object sender, ServiceEventArgs se)
        {
            ServiceCallback.NameChange(se.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

This host is then launched in my app like this:

```
var currentHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PubSubService));
currentHost.Open();
```

Up to this point it all looks good. Then I setup my client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="Zombie.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <Zombie.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CurrentVersion" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0.0.0.0</value>
            </setting>
        </Zombie.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPubSubService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8081/PubSubService/Service.svc"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                     algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/PubSubService/Service.svc"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IPubSubService"
                contract="PubSubClient.PubSubService.IPubSubService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPubSubService">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/chaks-pc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here's how I launch it:

```
    InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new ServiceCallback());
    PubSubServiceClient client = new PubSubServiceClient(context);

    MyEventCallbackHandler callbackHandler = CallbackHandler;
    MyEventCallbackEvent += callbackHandler;

    client.Subscribe();
```

I am getting the timeout error, and I have no clue what the issue is. I am launching both of the apps (client and service) from the same machine so the `localhost` address should not be an issue. Since they are on the same machine I don't see how a 1min timeout can be exceeded. This connection should be established in split seconds. Anyone can help me out here?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you set your timeouts to *different* values (for example 1 minute, two minutes, three minutes) to see *which* of your 1 minute timeouts you are hitting?

Comment: I haven't I will try that.

Comment: It's the sendTimeout. I reset that to 3min and thats the one that was returned in exception.

Comment: hm, that's strange. Does anything actually take the one minute? What does your program do in this minute?

Comment: At the moment? Nothing. I am just trying to figure out how to setup WindowsService with a WCF host so that I can talk to it from a GUI (client).

Comment: So your program is idle? Who gets the time out exception and where?

Comment: The client gets timeout exception when `Subscribe()` is called.

Comment: So the call *is* taking one minute? Did you set a breakpoint in the service? Is it hit?

Comment: It doesn't appear to reach the Service. Setting a breakpoint inside of the Service's `Subscribe()` method doesn't trigger it. What does that mean?

Comment: It means it could not connect. As a first step, disable the security on your binding, those errors can be a pain in... a certain bodypart because you never get real error messages (part of the security is not telling you what exactly fails). Try to remove that first when trying to find the error.

Comment: But security mode is set to `None`. Should I remove the whole `Security` tag?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. So I needed to disable the security on the Service side. I just created my binding configuration there, and turned the security off there. Now I can connect to it and the breakpoints are getting hit, as well as the timeout is gone. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Comment: if you want to post the comment about the Security as an answer i will be happy to accept it. Cheers!